# Tomar id de javascript a php

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un modal en el cual voy mostrar información de una base de datos, el cual lo logre con esta función:

```
function ver(id){

    $('.modal-body').load('php/CargarAlmacenamiento.php?id=12',function(){
        $('#modalAlmacenamiento').modal({show:true});
    });
}
```

pero la falla mía es que siempre me carga el mismo registro (en este ejemplo el que tenga el ID 12), pretendo que el id sea capturado por el que le tengo al botón del modal:

```
button class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAlmacenamiento" 
                             onclick="ver('?php echo $ver[0] ?>')"></button>
```

En la parte del php aparece el id de cada registro, pero como mencione anteriormente no lo toma al llevarlo a la función.

Gracias por su colaboración.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya haz intentado pasando el id al final de la url, algo así:

```
function ver(id){
    $('.modal-body').load('php/CargarAlmacenamiento.php?id='+id,function(){
        $('#modalAlmacenamiento').modal({show:true});
    });
}
```

Comment: LuisYm muchisimas gracias eso era lo que estaba buscando, esa era la respuesta.

Comment: Excelente, a segir trabajando..